# Problem reprojecting a shapefile with st_transform

Tags: reprojection-error

I have a few rasters (CRS 32632) and a shapefile with the coordinates of points that I need to study (CRS 2154). I need to crop my rasters with the shape to only keep the area where my points are, but therefore I need to reproject the shapefile in CRS 32632.

Here's my code

```
data <- st_read("inventory.shp")

st_transform (data, 32632)
```

This gives me the following error :

```
Warning message:
In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO") :
  Discarded datum Unknown based on GRS80 ellipsoid in CRS definition,
 but +towgs84= values preserved
```

Does anyone have a clue about how I could settle this?